# Is it bad to start your car in neutral while in motion?

Tags: transmission

Is it bad to start your car in neutral while in motion? Is it better to start it in neutral while sitting still?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are you talking for an auto or a manual transmission (or either)?

Comment: no harm. It is a potentially distracting thing to do, and so arguably dangerous depending on your skill level.

Comment: What do you mean by "bad"? Bad because it is unsafe? Or bad because it might damage something?

Comment: Paulster2...I am talking about an auto.

Comment: agentp...thanks. I have done it rarely several times throughout the years. I am asking for a female friend in which her car cuts off several times a day.

Comment: CharlieRB...Bad as in damaging to the transmission or even driveshaft.

Answer (score 1):

Neutral means no connection between engine and box - so makes no difference, but you need to stay aware of the other road users as you may be causing a hazard or missing something while trying to get your engine started.